# Strange fstream problem

Tags: c++, fstream

I have really strange problem. In Visual C++ express, I have very simple code, just:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
fstream file;
file.open("test.txt");
file<<"Hello";
file.close();
}
```

This same code works OK in my one project, but when I create now project and use this same lines of code, no file test.txt is created. Please, what is wrong?¨

EDIT: I expect to see test.txt in VS2008/project_name/debug - just like the first functional project does.

Comment: Where have you looked whether the file is created?

Comment: Where are you expecting the file to be created?

Comment: Did you check the project properties, most of all the working directory property?

Answer (score 3):

Canonical code to write to a file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream file;
    file.open("test.txt");
    if ( ! file.is_open() ) {
       cerr << "open error\n";
    }

    if ( ! (  file << "Hello" ) ) {
       cerr << "write error\n";
    }

   file.close();

}
```

Whenever you perform file I/O you must test every single operation, with the possible exception of closing a file, which it is not usually possible to recover from.

As for the file being created somewhere else - simply give it a weird name like `mxyzptlk.txt` and then search for it using Windows explorer.

Comment: Makes sense. So, why would a `file << "Hello"` or `file >> string` operation fail ? Is there a way to figure out why it fails ? It happens randomly in one of my programs... if you make the call several times, it ends up working, but I would rather not blindly loop until it does.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the executable is run in a different directory than it was before, making test.txt appear somewhere else.  Try using an absolute path, such as `"C:\\Users\\NoName\\Desktop\\test.txt"` (The double backslashes are needed as escape characters in C strings).

Answer (score 2):

`fstream::open()` takes two arguments: `filename` and `mode`. Since you are not providing the second, you may wish to check what the default argument in `fstream` is or provide `ios_base::out` yourself.

Furthermore, you may wish to check whether the file is open. It is possible that you do not have write permissions in the *current working directory* (where 'test.txt' will be written since you don't provide an absolute path). `fstream` provides the `is_open()` method as one way of checking this.

Lastly, think about indenting your code. While you only have a few lines there, code can soon become difficult to read without proper indentation. Sample code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("test.txt", ios_base::out);
    if (not file.is_open())
    {
        // Your error-handling code here
    }
    file << "Hello";
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and filter on file access and your process to determine whether the open/write is succeeding and where on disk it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Theres two ways to fix this. Either do:

file.open("test.txt", ios::out)

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("test.txt", ios::out);
    file<<"Hello";
    file.close();
}
```

Or you can create an ofstream instead of fstream.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open("test.txt");
    file<<"Hello";
    file.close();
}
```